# What hardware should I use for this hinge?

Tags: table-saw, tabletop

This is a continuation of another post where I was asking about a solution to easily add an outfeed wing to a table saw stand

I decided to go with the solution depicted below but I am having a hard time to find the proper hardware for building this.

[image]

[image]
Basically the outfeed table sits on a piece of wood that rotates around its longitudinal axis allowing the wing to get into the storage position (the wiremesh object)

The priciple is simple the hinge should be practically a pair of pins, one at each end screwed into the traversal piece of wood that supports the table saw end of the outfeed wing. The hinge/pins should support the weight of a 2'x4'x3/4' MDF plus whatever slides from the table saw ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wooden dowel.

No need to overthink this, dowel is used as the pivot pin or axle in many a traditional design and it can work very well even in cases of sustained use. Pick a strong hardwood (e.g. oak, beech, maple) and it's likely the pivots will outlive your need for the outfeed table.

To prevent rubbing against the framework you'll probably want to install some washers. Metal washers may do here but if you'd prefer a lower-friction alternative you can make a custom washer from a few of the plastics used in food packaging, e.g. LDPE, PP or PET. See [previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/protective-disc-between-moving-pieces-of-wood/3723#3723) .